# How to get the Boolean data from excel sheet using PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am get all the data from excel file using PHPExcel library.

But I am getting "1" for `True` and getting empty value for `False`.

I need 1/0 or True/False. (Not Empty)

**PHP Code**

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$file_path = "test.xlsx";
try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_path);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
print_R($sheetData);
```

**INPUT**

[image]

**Actual Output**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => Country
            [B] => Boolean
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => India
            [B] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [A] => US
            [B] => 
        )

)
```

Thanks Advance!

Comment: In PHP, 1 is a boolean true, 0 is a boolean false.... just cast to boolean.... e.g. `$data[2]['B'] = (bool) $data[2]['B'];`

Comment: I know, But `(bool) $sheetData[3]['B']` Always `Empty`. Why?

Comment: `(bool) $sheetData[3]['B']` should not give an empty result, it should give a boolean false. Do a var_dump() rather than print_r() of the array to see what it really contains

Comment: Ok. Any way to get "0/False" instead of `empty`? I need to display it.

Comment: It should already be a boolean value, it's just the way print_r displays booleans.... use a var_dump() instead to check..... learn about the differences between print_r and var_dump